# The word foresaw and its morphemes

Tags: american-english, morphology, derivational-morphology, inflectional-morphology

I need help with the word foresaw. I know that the morphemes for foresaw are {fore} and {saw} but what kind of morpehmes are they (derivational/inflection) and what are their category and function

Answer (score -2):

'Fore' going back to Latin 'per' via Norsk 'fyrr' and then 'saw' being the simple past of 'see', whose roots are in Greek 'sekw', 'to follow', in this case with the eyes.

Beyond that I don't really understand the question

Comment: "Fore" is cognate to Latin "per", not descended from it.